# Integration of multiple similar functions into one function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have two Matlab functions `f=fun1(x)` and `f=fun2(x,y)` which are very alike and I would like to integrate them into a single function `f=fun(x,y)`.

For the first function I have

```
function f=fun1(x)

N=1000; % Some large number.

for j=1:N
    f=x^2;
end
```

and for the second function

```
function f=fun2(x,y)

N=1000; % Some large number.

for j=1:N
    f=x^2;
    f=f+y;
end
```

. So actually `fun1` is sort of a subfunction of `fun2`. I would like to construct a function `f=fun(x,y,method_number)` like

```
function f=fun(x,y,method_number)

N=1000; % Some large number.

for j=1:N
    f=x^2; % If method_number==1 run only this command....
    f=f+y; % If method_number==2 run also this command.
end
```

This is just a short simplified example of the problem I want to solve. My real problem is that I have three long functions `f=fun1(x,y,z)`, `f=fun2(x,y)` and `f=fun3(x)` with several resemblances and of which `fun3` is a subfunction of `fun2` and `fun2` is a subfunction of `fun1` in the same meaning as here above. I do not believe using `switch-case` or `if-else` everywhere is an option since `N` can be very large, which would be inefficient. Furthermore, it would completely destroy the layout of the code.

Comment: Take a look at [local functions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html) and [nested functions](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html)

Answer (score 3):

In your case it seem each of your function have a different number of input argument. If it is the case, the matlab function [`nargin`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) can detect that and you do not have to specify an additional `method` parameter.

For example:

```
function f = fun(x,y,z)

switch nargin
    case 1
        f = x.^2;            %// run only if ONE argument was specified

    case 2
        f = fun(x) + y;      %// run only if TWO arguments were specified

    case 3
        f = fun(x,y) ./ z ;  %// run only if THREE arguments were specified

    otherwise
        disp('Houston, we have a problem !!') ; %// run if NO or more than 3 arguments were specified
end
```

You can call `f` with one argument, two or three without trouble, Matlab will only execute the function corresponding to the proper number of argument.

The function, when passed with 3 arguments, can call on itself to calculate the part with 2 argument (which can call on itself to calculate the part from the first argument).

---

Case two: If the recursion really cannot be taken out of the loop, the classic `if ... then` will work:

```
function f = fun(x,y,z)

if nargin == 3
        threeArgs = true ;
        twoArgs   = true ;
elseif nargin == 2
        threeArgs = false ;
        twoArgs   = true ;
elseif nargin == 1
        threeArgs = false ;
        twoArgs   = false ;
end

for it=1:1e6
    f = x.^2; %// If method_number==1 run only this command....
    %// ... other computations
    if twoArgs
        f = f + y ; %// If method_number==2 run also this command.
        %// ... other computations
        if threeArgs
            f = f ./z ; %// If method_number==3 run also this command.
            %// ... other computations
        end
        %// ... other computations only relevant to f(x,y)
    end
    %// ... other computations only relevant to f(x)
end
```

This would totally exclude recursion and would insure the minimum number of computation.

---

Now I realise this looks a bit clumsy code and you asked for a solution without `if ... then` and `switch`. Depending on your calculation, there is a method which can avoid any `if` or `switch` but may not be practical for all cases.

The idea is to assign an `invariant` operator to `y` or `z` in case they are not called.

Example:

```
function f = fun(x,y,z)

if nargin < 3 ; z = 1 ; end
if nargin < 2 ; y = 0 ; end

for it=1:1e6
    f = x.^2; 
    %// ... other computations just based on X

    f = f + y ; %// This always run, but if "y" wasn't specified, it does not modify the result (f+0=f)
    %// ... other computations

    f = f ./z ; %// This always run, but if "z" wasn't specified, it does not modify the result (f./1=f)
    %// ... other computations

end
```

This avoid any flow branch in the code but i would only keep this method for simple cases, because the computations are always done regardless of the case (although may be some JIT compiler are smart enough to not bother doing 'no effect' operations).

Comment: Nice answer... inspite of the [misquote](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Houston,_we_have_a_problem) :-P

Comment: Seems nice, but I am unsure of recursive function calls, where the function (in the real problem) starts with a for-loop. I might be wrong, but looking at it in the first place, adding the loop might end in several nested for-loops, which can be avoided by avoiding the recursive function calls.

Comment: @Hoki As I tried to explain in my last paragraph, the actual problem has several resemblances, not just one. And they're sometimes even in a `for` loop which is executed a large number of times. Accordingly, the use of `switch-case` and `if-else` is inappropriate.

Comment: @Adriaan. If there are pitfall in using this method then you need to give more detail about the structure of your functions, what is common, what is not, what is in loop and what is not. Otherwise I'll be just stabbing in the dark. Also, in the case of 2 and 3 argument, if `x` has been calculated already in a first step (even if it took a loop), it doesn't have to be recalculated in the next loops, just use `x(i)` in these loops.

Comment: @Adriaan, I modified the answer to give other options

Comment: @Hoki I will think of a more elaborate example to demonstrate how the resemble more than in the simple example. I'm also thinking function pointers might help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid checking for the number of input arguments `nargin` `N`-times by duplicating code. You will check once, which computation should be done and repeat it `N` times. In this example, the for-loop is the duplicated code. To some extent, this might be okay.

```
function f = fun(x, y, z)
N = 1000;

switch nargin

    %// Do something if only x is given
    case 1
    for j = 1:N
        f = x.^2;
    end

    %// Do something else if only x and y are given
    case 2
    for j = 1:N
        f = x.^2 + y;
    end

    %// Do something else if x, y and z are given
    case 3
    for j = 1:N
        f = x.^2 + y - z;
    end

    otherwise
        error('Use fun.m with 1, 2 or 3 arguments only!');
end
end
```

This is a variation of Hoki`s answer. In fact, I started from it adding the for-loop and removing the recursive function calls by adding duplicated code.